# Validate a URL with Regex in Ionic

Tags: regex, forms, ionic-framework

I am working on an Ionic app and trying to create a regular expression to match a website URL for some form validation. Here is the regex I am using:

`^((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?$`

While I know that this is not a “perfect” regex for validating a URL, I am getting inconsistencies between using the regex in ionic vs. my web tests.

For example, i plugged the same regex into http://www.regex101.com and several examples are working just fine:

http://www.google.com

[google.com](http://google.com)

[www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

However, when I run my ionic app, **none** of my patterns are matching.

I know that I am using `Validators.pattern()` properly because I have already added a regex validator for email inputs. I also know that I’m using it properly because I am able to plug in simple regex patterns, like `http` and the validation works fine.

Somewhere along the way, the Ionic pattern is failing to parse as a normal regex would. Perhaps my pattern is using a character that Ionic does not recognize or parses differently?

Is there something about using regex in Ionic that I am missing?

Here is how I am setting up the validations for my various form controls. Note that the pattern for organizerEmail is working.

```
let formGroup: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
  title: ['', Validators.required],
  venue: ['', Validators.required],
  streetAddress: ['', Validators.required],
  city: ['', Validators.required],
  zipCode: ['', Validators.required],
  price: [''],
  description: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.maxLength(this.descriptionMax), Validators.required])],
  eventUrl: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern('^((http|ftp|https):\/\/)?([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&\/~+#-])?$'), Validators.required])],
  contactName: ['', Validators.required],
  organizerEmail: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9._]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$'), Validators.required])],
  phoneNumber: [''],
});
```

Here is the HTML input uses the form control:

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked color="light">Website</ion-label>
    <ion-input formControlName="eventUrl" type="url" placeholder="Website"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

Comment: *Note that the pattern for organizerEmail is working.* - it does not work correctly. Escape all ``\`` again. Replace `\/` with `/`. Remove `^` and `$`. E.g. `Validators.pattern('^((http|ftp|https)://)?([\\w_-]+(?:(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+))([\\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?$')`

Comment: Just a couple of notes: `https?` matches both `http` and `https`, is quicker and shorter. The token `\w` includes `_`, so you don't need to add it to the character class.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That did it! It was the escaping the backslash that I was missing.

Comment: Have you set the Regex101 regex type to Javascript ?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you want to submit an answer I will choose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may fix the pattern by escaping the backslashes and you may remove the anchors as they are implicitly added by the engine. You may also remove unnecessary groups.

Use

```
Validators.pattern('(?:(?:(?:ht|f)tp)s?://)?[\\w_-]+(?:\\.[\\w_-]+)+([\\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?')
```

Here is the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/b69gYs/1).

The email checking regex must escape the `.` correctly, too:

```
Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9._]+[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}')
```